# how to calculate the mean of a variable between two date

Tags: r, date, average

I would like to calculate the mean of a variable between two date, below is the reproducible data frame.

```
year <- c(1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
      1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,1996,
      1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,
      1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997)
month <- c("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")
station <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
         "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

concentration <- as.numeric(round(runif(48,20,40),1))

df <- data.frame(year,month,station,concentration)


id <- c(1,2,3,4)
station1996 <- c("A","A","B","B")
station1997 <- c("B","A","A","B")
start <- c("06/01/1996","07/01/1996","07/01/1996","08/01/1996")
end <- c("04/01/1997","04/01/1997","04/01/1997","05/01/1997")

participant <- data.frame(id,station1996,station1997,start,end)
participant$start <- as.Date(participant$start, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
participant$end <- as.Date(participant$end, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

So I have two dataset as below

```
df
   year month station concentration
1  1996   JAN       A          24.4
2  1996   FEB       A          37.0
3  1996   MAR       A          39.5
4  1996   APR       A          28.0
...
45 1997   SEP       B          37.7
46 1997   OCT       B          35.2
47 1997   NOV       B          26.8
48 1997   DEC       B          40.0

participant
  id station1996 station1997      start        end
1  1           A           B 1996-06-01 1997-04-01
2  2           A           A 1996-07-01 1997-04-01
3  3           B           A 1996-07-01 1997-04-01
4  4           B           B 1996-08-01 1997-05-01
```

For each id, I would like to calculate the average concentration between the start and end date (month year). Noted that the station might change between years.

For example for id=1, I would like to calculate the average concentration between JUN 1996 AND APR 1997. This should be based on the concentration from JUN 1996 to DEC 1996 at station A, and JAN 1997 to APR 1997 at station B.

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: step 1: convert `start` and `end` to `Date` or `POSIXct` format, and combine `year` and `month` as a new column of the same format.

Comment: You may also convert these to strings in the form like "1997-10".  Then you can do like `mean(concentration[date >= start & date <= end])`

Comment: `library(zoo); as.yearmon(participant$start)` etc... might also be handy in this case if you don't want to deal with the slightly clunkier POSIXct formats.

Comment: Thanks Toomet, but I need to account for the change of station

Comment: I have edited the original question. is it a must to specify day? although I only have month and year

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table solution. The basic idea is to enumerate all the dates in the start-end range as `yearmon`, for each `id`, and then use that as an index into the concentration table `df`. It's a bit convoluted so hopefully someone will come along and show you a simpler way.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)          # for as.yearmon(...)
setDT(df)             # convert to data.table
setDT(participant)
df[, yrmon:= as.yearmon(paste(year,month,sep="-"), format="%Y-%B")]   # add year-month column
p.melt <- reshape(participant, varying=2:3, direction="long", sep="", timevar="year")
x <- participant[, .(date=seq(start,end,by="month")), by=id]
x[, c("year","yrmon"):=.(year(date),as.yearmon(date))]           # add year and year-month
x[p.melt, station:=station, on=c("id","year")]                   # add station
x[df, conc:= concentration, on=c("yrmon","station"), nomatch=0]  # add concentration
setorder(x,id)    # not necessary, but makes it easier to interpret x
result <- x[, .(mean.conc=mean(conc)), by=id]                    # mean(conc) by id
result
#    id mean.conc
# 1:  1  28.61818
# 2:  2  28.56000
# 3:  3  28.44000
# 4:  4  29.60000
```

So, first we convert everything to data.tables. Then we add a `yrmon` column to `df` for indexing later. Then we create `p.melt` by reshaping `participant` to long format, so that the station is in one column and the indicator (1996 or 1997) is in a separate column. Then we create a temporary table, `x` with the sequence of dates for each `id`, and add the year and yrmon for each of those dates. Then we merge that with `p.melt` on `id` and `year` to add a station column to `x`. Then we use `yrmon` and `station` to merge `x` with `df` to get the appropriate concentration. Then we simply aggregate `conc` by `id` in `x` using `mean(...)`.